# Programatically remove just the final slash from the path returned by "%~dp0"

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, cmd

In a CMD .BAT file, how may I programatically remove just the final slash from the path returned by "%~dp0"?

This is to solve the failure of my command

```
subst F: "%~dp0"
```

giving

```
S:\TLIB distribution\FG trial>subst F: "S:\TLIB distribution\FG trial\"
Path not found - S:\TLIB distribution\FG trial\
```

whereas

```
S:\TLIB distribution\FG trial>subst F: "S:\TLIB distribution\FG trial"
S:\TLIB distribution\FG trial>
```

succeeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1:

```
pushd "%~dp0"
subst f: .
popd
```

Option 2:

```
for %%A in ("%~dp0\.") do subst f: "%~fA"
```

Option 3:

```
for %%A in ("%~f0\..") do subst f: "%~fA"
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll go for 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SETLOCAL  EnableDelayedExpansion
SET str=%~dp0
SET str=!str:~0,-1!
ECHO %str%
SUBST F: "%str%"
```

This will return your string without the last character (\).

EDIT: It only works if you aren't in the drive root. So use dbenham's solution or catch the root case with an if statement. I won't delete my post because it's still a valide answer to the question in the title (Programatically remove just the final slash from the path returned by “%~dp0”) and might help in other cases.

Comment: This could fail if the script resides in the drive root.

Comment: Confirmed: http://i.imgur.com/OvY9DOI.png . SUBST Path syntax is irregular, despite no mention in https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/subst.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Right, it only works if you aren't at root. So use dbenham's solution or catch the root case with an if statement.

Comment: "or catch the root case with an if statement" I wonder how many other failure cases that would leave.